# Css row split with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

```js
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: false
});
```

```css
/*=================================================================
GENERAL
=================================================================*/
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

/*=================================================================
COLORS
=================================================================*/
.blue{
 color:#0091D7;
}
.light-blue{
 color:#0091D7
}
.dark-blue{
 color:#003148;
}
.background-blue{
 background-color:#0091D7;
 color: #fff;
}
.background-dark-blue{
 background-color:#003148;
 color: #fff;
}

.font-w-600{
 font-weight: 600;
}
/*=================================================================
HEADER
=================================================================*/
.header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.header  img{
    height: 60px;
}

/*=================================================================
MAIN=================================================================*/
 .main {

  background-color: white;
  background-image: url("img/CRYPTOCLUB_02.jpg");
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left top;


}
.main a {
 font-size: 2.5rem;
 margin:100px 0 50px 0;
 display: block;
}

.join-now{
   background: #003148;
    font-weight: 600;
    border: 4px solid #0091d7;
    float: right;
    box-shadow: 5px #000;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px #202020
}
.join-now:hover {
    color: #0062cc;
    background-color: #003148;
    background-color: #003148;

}

/*SLIDER SECTION CSS*/

.carousel img{
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px !important;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
 
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.carousel-item .carousel-caption{
 position: relative;
}
.carousel-item > .carousel-caption p{
    font-size: 12px;
    max-width: 70%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.carousel-item > .carousel-caption h5{
 font-size: 16px;
    max-width: 70%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    text-indent: -999px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
.contact-us h5 ,h3,h4 ,p {
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.contact-us h5{
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.contact-us p{
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.footer img {
 height: 40px;
}
.footer p{
  font-size: 0.6rem;
}
.line-strip{
 width: 100%;
 background-color:#0091D7;
 height: 10px;
}
#triangle-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-8iPTk2s/jMVj81dnzb/iFR2sdA7u06vHJyyLlAd4snFpCl/SnyUjRrbdJsw1pGIl"
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <title>Bitcoin</title>
</head>
  <div class="container-fluid mb-4">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6 background-blue">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/bill-gates.jpg" alt="First slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
    <p>“Bitcoin is better than currency in that you don’t have to be physically in the same place, and in the future, financial transactions will eventually be digital, universal and almost free.”</p>
    <h5 class=" bold text-uppercase">bill gates</h5>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/bill-gates.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
    <p>“Bitcoin is better than currency in that you don’t have to be physically in the same place, and in the future, financial transactions will eventually be digital, universal and almost free.”</p>
    <h5 class=" bold text-uppercase">bill gates</h5>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/bill-gates.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
    <p>“Bitcoin is better than currency in that you don’t have to be physically in the same place, and in the future, financial transactions will eventually be digital, universal and almost free.”</p>
    <h5 class=" bold text-uppercase">bill gates</h5>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    </div>
   </div><!-- end of sm-6 -->
   <div class="col-sm-6 background-dark-blue">
    <div id="slider2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#slider2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#slider2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#slider2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/bill-gates.jpg" alt="First slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
    <p>“Bitcoin is better than currency in that you don’t have to be physically in the same place, and in the future, financial transactions will eventually be digital, universal and almost free.”</p>
    <h5 class=" bold text-uppercase">bill gates</h5>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/bill-gates.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
    <p>“Bitcoin is better than currency in that you don’t have to be physically in the same place, and in the future, financial transactions will eventually be digital, universal and almost free.”</p>
    <h5 class=" bold text-uppercase">bill gates</h5>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/bill-gates.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
    <p>“Bitcoin is better than currency in that you don’t have to be physically in the same place, and in the future, financial transactions will eventually be digital, universal and almost free.”</p>
    <h5 class=" bold text-uppercase">bill gates</h5>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#slider2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#slider2" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    </div>
   </div><!-- end of col-sm-6  -->
  </div><!-- end of row -->
 </div><!-- end of container -->


  
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

I'm having troubles to make this split of columns with the bootstrap v4 any idea how to achieve this Column split  i have an idea making a triangle with css but if use add more text in description that will be more short than the row width ,
I'm having troubles to make this split of columns with the bootstrap v4 any idea how to achieve this Column split  i have an idea making a triangle with css but if use add more text in description that will be more short than the row width , [image: here]

Comment: share your code

Comment: Best we can do is `skewX()`, `scale()` and `overflow:hidden` without seeing actual code

Comment: @Sagar i added code sniper

Comment: @ppajer i added code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `skew` your containers (and inverse skew the content to make it appear normal). Then in order to fill left/right missing space you could use `:before`/`:after` pseudo-elements.

### Code I added:

```
.background-blue:before{
    z-index:1001;
    background: #0091D7;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left:-60px;
    top: 0;
    width: 70px;
    height:100%;
}

.background-dark-blue:after{
    z-index:1001;
    background: #003148;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right:-60px;
    top: 0;
    width: 70px;
    height:100%;
}

.background-blue, .background-dark-blue {
  -moz-transform: skew(-5deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-5deg);
  transform: skew(-5deg);
}
/* inverse skew the content */
.background-blue .slide,
.background-dark-blue .slide{
  -moz-transform: skew(5deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(5deg);
  transform: skew(5deg);
}
```

### DEMO:

```js
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: false
});
```

```css
/*=================================================================
GENERAL
=================================================================*/
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

/*=================================================================
COLORS
=================================================================*/
.blue{
    color:#0091D7;
}
.light-blue{
    color:#0091D7
}
.dark-blue{
    color:#003148;
}


.background-blue:before{
    z-index:1001;
    background: #0091D7;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left:-60px;
    top: 0;
    width: 70px;
    height:100%;
}

.background-dark-blue:after{
    z-index:1001;
    background: #003148;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right:-60px;
    top: 0;
    width: 70px;
    height:100%;
}

.background-blue, .background-dark-blue {
  -moz-transform: skew(-5deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-5deg);
  transform: skew(-5deg);
}

.background-blue .slide,
.background-dark-blue .slide{
  -moz-transform: skew(5deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(5deg);
  transform: skew(5deg);
}


.background-blue{
    background-color:#0091D7;
    color: #fff;
}

.background-dark-blue{
    background-color:#003148;
    color: #fff;
}

.font-w-600{
    font-weight: 600;
}
/*=================================================================
HEADER
=================================================================*/
.header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.header  img{
    height: 60px;
}

/*=================================================================
MAIN=================================================================*/
 .main {

  background-color: white;
  background-image: url("img/CRYPTOCLUB_02.jpg");
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left top;


}
.main a {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    margin:100px 0 50px 0;
    display: block;
}

.join-now{
      background: #003148;
    font-weight: 600;
    border: 4px solid #0091d7;
    float: right;
    box-shadow: 5px #000;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px #202020
}
.join-now:hover {
    color: #0062cc;
    background-color: #003148;
    background-color: #003148;

}

/*SLIDER SECTION CSS*/

.carousel img{
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px !important;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
 
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.carousel-item .carousel-caption{
    position: relative;
}
.carousel-item > .carousel-caption p{
    font-size: 12px;
    max-width: 70%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.carousel-item > .carousel-caption h5{
    font-size: 16px;
    max-width: 70%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    text-indent: -999px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
.contact-us h5 ,h3,h4 ,p {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.contact-us h5{
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.contact-us p{
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.footer img {
    height: 40px;
}
.footer p{
  font-size: 0.6rem;
}
.line-strip{
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#0091D7;
    height: 10px;
}
#triangle-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-8iPTk2s/jMVj81dnzb/iFR2sdA7u06vHJyyLlAd4snFpCl/SnyUjRrbdJsw1pGIl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Bitcoin</title>
</head>
  <div class="container-fluid mb-4">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 background-blue">
                <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/bill-gates.jpg" alt="First slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <p>“Bitcoin is better than currency in that you don’t have to be physically in the same place, and in the future, financial transactions will eventually be digital, universal and almost free.”</p>
                <h5 class=" bold text-uppercase">bill gates</h5>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/bill-gates.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <p>“Bitcoin is better than currency in that you don’t have to be physically in the same place, and in the future, financial transactions will eventually be digital, universal and almost free.”</p>
                <h5 class=" bold text-uppercase">bill gates</h5>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/bill-gates.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <p>“Bitcoin is better than currency in that you don’t have to be physically in the same place, and in the future, financial transactions will eventually be digital, universal and almost free.”</p>
                <h5 class=" bold text-uppercase">bill gates</h5>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
                </div>
            </div><!-- end of sm-6 -->
            <div class="col-sm-6 background-dark-blue">
                <div id="slider2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#slider2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#slider2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#slider2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/bill-gates.jpg" alt="First slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <p>“Bitcoin is better than currency in that you don’t have to be physically in the same place, and in the future, financial transactions will eventually be digital, universal and almost free.”</p>
                <h5 class=" bold text-uppercase">bill gates</h5>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/bill-gates.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <p>“Bitcoin is better than currency in that you don’t have to be physically in the same place, and in the future, financial transactions will eventually be digital, universal and almost free.”</p>
                <h5 class=" bold text-uppercase">bill gates</h5>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/bill-gates.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <p>“Bitcoin is better than currency in that you don’t have to be physically in the same place, and in the future, financial transactions will eventually be digital, universal and almost free.”</p>
                <h5 class=" bold text-uppercase">bill gates</h5>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#slider2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#slider2" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
                </div>
            </div><!-- end of col-sm-6  -->
        </div><!-- end of row -->
    </div><!-- end of container -->


  
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: it makes text so blur

Comment: how to make other side of this

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
.background-blue::before {
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 200px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
    border-right: 35px solid #043248;
  }
```

result is 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Will add content as soon as I get the chance. Till that time you can play around with this.

```css
.left {
  height: 300px;
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

.left:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 150px solid blue;
  border-left: 20px solid red;
  width: 0;
}

.right {
  height: 300px;
  flex: 1;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.right:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 150px solid red;
  border-right: 20px solid blue;
  width: 0;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use linear-gradient on the row div:

```
.background {
  background:linear-gradient(100deg,#0091D7 50%,#003148 50.1%);
}
```

Full code:

```js
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: false
});
```

```css
/*=================================================================
GENERAL
=================================================================*/
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

/*=================================================================
COLORS
=================================================================*/
.blue{
 color:#0091D7;
}
.light-blue{
 color:#0091D7
}
.dark-blue{
 color:#003148;
}
.background {
  background:linear-gradient(100deg,#0091D7 50%,#003148 50.1%);
}
.background-blue{
 color: #fff;
}
.background-dark-blue{
 color: #fff;
}

.font-w-600{
 font-weight: 600;
}
/*=================================================================
HEADER
=================================================================*/
.header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.header  img{
    height: 60px;
}

/*=================================================================
MAIN=================================================================*/
 .main {

  background-color: white;
  background-image: url("img/CRYPTOCLUB_02.jpg");
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left top;


}
.main a {
 font-size: 2.5rem;
 margin:100px 0 50px 0;
 display: block;
}

.join-now{
   background: #003148;
    font-weight: 600;
    border: 4px solid #0091d7;
    float: right;
    box-shadow: 5px #000;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px #202020
}
.join-now:hover {
    color: #0062cc;
    background-color: #003148;
    background-color: #003148;

}

/*SLIDER SECTION CSS*/

.carousel img{
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px !important;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
 
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.carousel-item .carousel-caption{
 position: relative;
}
.carousel-item > .carousel-caption p{
    font-size: 12px;
    max-width: 70%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.carousel-item > .carousel-caption h5{
 font-size: 16px;
    max-width: 70%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    text-indent: -999px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
.contact-us h5 ,h3,h4 ,p {
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.contact-us h5{
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.contact-us p{
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.footer img {
 height: 40px;
}
.footer p{
  font-size: 0.6rem;
}
.line-strip{
 width: 100%;
 background-color:#0091D7;
 height: 10px;
}
#triangle-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-8iPTk2s/jMVj81dnzb/iFR2sdA7u06vHJyyLlAd4snFpCl/SnyUjRrbdJsw1pGIl"
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <title>Bitcoin</title>
</head>
  <div class="container-fluid mb-4">
 <div class="row background">
   <div class="col-sm-6 background-blue">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/bill-gates.jpg" alt="First slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
    <p>“Bitcoin is better than currency in that you don’t have to be physically in the same place, and in the future, financial transactions will eventually be digital, universal and almost free.”</p>
    <h5 class=" bold text-uppercase">bill gates</h5>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/bill-gates.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
    <p>“Bitcoin is better than currency in that you don’t have to be physically in the same place, and in the future, financial transactions will eventually be digital, universal and almost free.”</p>
    <h5 class=" bold text-uppercase">bill gates</h5>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/bill-gates.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
    <p>“Bitcoin is better than currency in that you don’t have to be physically in the same place, and in the future, financial transactions will eventually be digital, universal and almost free.”</p>
    <h5 class=" bold text-uppercase">bill gates</h5>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    </div>
   </div><!-- end of sm-6 -->
   <div class="col-sm-6 background-dark-blue">
    <div id="slider2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#slider2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#slider2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#slider2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/bill-gates.jpg" alt="First slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
    <p>“Bitcoin is better than currency in that you don’t have to be physically in the same place, and in the future, financial transactions will eventually be digital, universal and almost free.”</p>
    <h5 class=" bold text-uppercase">bill gates</h5>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/bill-gates.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
    <p>“Bitcoin is better than currency in that you don’t have to be physically in the same place, and in the future, financial transactions will eventually be digital, universal and almost free.”</p>
    <h5 class=" bold text-uppercase">bill gates</h5>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/bill-gates.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
    <p>“Bitcoin is better than currency in that you don’t have to be physically in the same place, and in the future, financial transactions will eventually be digital, universal and almost free.”</p>
    <h5 class=" bold text-uppercase">bill gates</h5>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#slider2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#slider2" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    </div>
   </div><!-- end of col-sm-6  -->
  </div><!-- end of row -->
 </div><!-- end of container -->


  
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: very  nice clean solution how to make reverse

Comment: @Albertqerimi simply adjust the deg of gradient ... use `80deg` instead of `100deg`